# how to validate svn credentials using ant script

Tags: svn, ant, svnkit

I have to commit some code to the svn using ant script, Before committing to the SVN i should validate the credentials ,Is there any command in svn for validating the username and password from ant script

Comment: What do you mean by "validate"?

Comment: it is going to fail otherwise, right? what is the issue?

Comment: Before doing the update or commit from svn i need to check whether that credentials are valid or not..?

Answer (score 1):

No, special command for validating credentials does not exist in SVN

but: you can to use *any* SVN command for accessing remote repository and use `--username` and `--password` option in it

but **BEWARE**: 1) nor successful nor failed command doesn't return exit-code|error-code to caller, you have to validate and *check output 2) even successful READ command doesn't mean "OK" for WRITE command (you can test on URL with anonymous read access or user can have only read-access to test-URL)

I think, best solution (dirty hack) for testing will be complex of

- Special "blackhole" URL, with `$authenticated = rw` permissions on it
- Pre-commit hook, which block all commits to $BLACKHOLE (you don't want to have useless commits in repo)
- `svn ci $BLACKHOLE --username ... --password ...` as test-tool